# Is it okay to use while when fetching data using php + MySQLi?

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, while-loop

Is it okay to use while when fetching data using php + MySQLi? Can it be prerequisite for any obvious issues?

```
$getpost->bind_result($returned_post);
while($getpost->fetch()){

    echo($returned_post);

}
```

Comment: "Is it not wrong to..." is confusing.  Do you mean "Is it okay to..."?

Comment: A billion records = a billion iterations. So, keep your data to a controlled amount (ie: pagination) (assuming you have a ridiculous time out)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is normal when mysqli_stmt_fetch() is called to fetch data, the MySQL client/server protocol places the data for the bound columns into the specified variables var1, ....

see this example:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

/* prepare statement */
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT Code, Name FROM Country ORDER BY Name LIMIT 5")) {
    $stmt->execute();

    /* bind variables to prepared statement */
    $stmt->bind_result($col1, $col2);

    /* fetch values */
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        printf("%s %s\n", $col1, $col2);
    }

    /* close statement */
    $stmt->close();
}
/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();

?>
```

you can read more in:

> http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php